# Google App Engine Server in netbeans 7.2 Error Missing value for property jvmargs

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to use Google App Engine on Netbeans 7.2. I get the plugin from http://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/NetBeans7.2/ , but when I am running it, I get "Missing value for property jvmargs".

I use sample project, so there shouldn't be any problem at all.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Check and make sure your PATH environment variable includes the Program Files/Java/jdk.#.#_##/bin directory.  If it is pointed at something else it probably won't work that's what my problem was. Make sure your project is using 6 JDK or lower because google app engine does not support JDK 7 at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Found a post somewhere that said to use the plugin for Netbeans 6.7 which does mostly work in Netbeans 7.2.1.

```
Had to do the following to get it working. 
- Goto Plugin->Settings and add 
  http://kenai.com/downloads/nbappengine/1.0_NetBeans671/updates.xml
- Goto Plugin->Available Plugins search for Google and install all the appengine plugins
- Create a appengine server under services
- Create a new project for an app server other than appengine (i used glassfish)
- After the project is created goto properties->run and switch to app engine
- Add false to appengine-web.xml


I'm running Windows 8, Netbeans 7.2.1, jdk1.7.0_11
```